# Is this whole line of CSS required to change colour of background?

Tags: css, wordpress

I have been trying to remove the background colour of my "Home" button on my navbar.

I used the below code and this has done what i wanted to do:

```html
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a, .navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:focus {
 background-color:#818d89;
}
```

I'm just wondering if this is bad coding and whether everything written there is necessary?

[image]
It's the white box i was aiming to remove/colour the same as the navbar

```html
<div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-header">
   <div class="title-logo-wrapper">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="http://localhost/wordpress/" title="">
     <img src="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/cropped-RCT-logo-1.png" alt=""></a>
   </div>
        <div class="navbar-toggle-wrapper">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#main-navigation">
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle Navigation</span>
   </button>
     </div>
    </div>
  <div id="main-navigation" class="collapse navbar-collapse"><ul id="menu-navigation" class="nav navbar-nav"><li id="menu-item-16" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-item current_page_item menu-item-home menu-item-16 active"><a title="Home" href="http://localhost/wordpress">Home</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-92" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-92"><a title="About Us" href="http://localhost/wordpress/about/">About Us</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-94" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-94"><a title="Sponsorship" href="http://localhost/wordpress/sponsorship/">Sponsorship</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-95" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-95"><a title="Blog" href="http://localhost/wordpress/blog/">Blog</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-487" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-487 dropdown"><a title="Get Involved" href="#" class="dropdown-toggle">Get Involved <span class="caret-wrap"><span class="caret"></span></span></a>
<ul role="menu" class="dropdown-menu">
 <li id="menu-item-479" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-479"><a title="Tell us your story" href="http://localhost/wordpress/tell-us-your-story/">Tell us your story</a></li>
 <li id="menu-item-482" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-482"><a title="Volunteer" href="http://localhost/wordpress/volunteer/">Volunteer</a></li>
 <li id="menu-item-486" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-486"><a title="Tours and Visits" href="http://localhost/wordpress/tours-and-visits/">Tours and Visits</a></li>
</ul>
</li>

<a title="Home" href="http://localhost/wordpress">Home</a>
<li id="menu-item-16" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-item current_page_item menu-item-home menu-item-16 active"><a title="Home" href="http://localhost/wordpress">Home</a></li>
```

Comment: Without seeing the HTML, it's impossible to say.

Comment: the background-color of the link is set by bootstrap css ( i guess ) so yes, you might need a very specific path when writing the selectors to change that background-color

Comment: I'm not sure you need the `.navbar-default` part in the selectors. Are there other elements in the code, outside of `.navbar-default`, that have class `.navbar-nav`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the html you could use the `parent`'s element ID.

```
#home_box > a:hover {
background-color:#818d89;
}
```

I will edit my answer if you supply the html.

Comment: This only targets the hovered state, not the non-hovered state as in the OP's example.

Comment: Yeah, I know. As I said, he can use the `parent`'s ID to start with. Without the HTML, it's quite impossible to give a detailed answer.

Comment: Hi @Sparky, thanks, i have edited my post to include html.

Comment: @lomomeg This is the **** of wordpress or drag&drop software. Loads of unnecessary classes. It **does** work like it should, but it can be extremely simplified.

Comment: @lomomeg What is the parent element of the `<a>`?